# 2 models select on string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, viewmodel

Im trying to learn myself C# MVC4 with visual studio 2010.

What i want to do is get the full output of 2 models on 1 view selected on someones username.

So if i go to /Teams/Details/1
I will get all the info from the models players and teams.

Models:

```
    public class Players
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string coach { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
}

    public class Teams
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string coach { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using voetbal.Models;

namespace voetbal.Controllers
{
    public class TeamsController : Controller
    {
        private TeamsDBContext db = new TeamsDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /Teams/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Teams.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Teams/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
            if (teams == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teams);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Teams/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Teams/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Teams teams)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                teams.coach = User.Identity.Name;
                db.Teams.Add(teams);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(teams);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Teams/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
            if (teams == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teams);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Teams/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Teams teams)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(teams).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(teams);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Teams/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
            if (teams == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teams);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Teams/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
            db.Teams.Remove(teams);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I have absolutely how to get this done, i have tried a viewmodel class but i have no idea how to get this information on someones coach name.

Im looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Can you add your controller action code?

Comment: How are you mapping your Db to classes?

Comment: Thank you, i included the controller by editing my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to skin this cat, but one thing you have to first see is that you're not sending back even one instance of both models. If you examine the code for the `Details` action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
    if (teams == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(teams);
}
```

clearly all we are sending back is one instance of the `Teams` model. So, let's examine an **option** that we have. Consider the following code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    Teams teams = db.Teams.Find(id);
    if (teams == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // get the list of players into a List<Players>
    var players ...

    var model = new Tuple<Teams, List<Players>>(teams, players);

    return View(model);
}
```

now in the View we can set our model to this (**note you will need to fully qualify `Teams` and `Players` in the @model declaration**):

```
@model Tuple<Teams, List<Players>>
```

and from there we can do stuff like:

```
Model.Item1.Name
```

or:

```
Model.Item2[0].Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i really appreciate! Could you tell me what i should have to do @ the var players ... part?

Comment: @JasonHoendervanger: you need to go get the players with a DB context just like you did the teams. If the `Players` isn't in the `TeamsDbContext` then you'll need to either add it to that context or build a new one. Either way, you're going to need to go to the database and get the `Players` for the team they want details for.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example? I can't get this to work. I don't know where to provide the context. I do have a context provided in the Players.cs model.

Comment: by using [ var players = db2.Players.ToList(); ] i am able to receive the players list, now i only want to see the players where the coach is for example Jason

Comment: You can use a `Where` on that.